# Three text fields for one database entry for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, textfield

I currently have one text field for a date entry, I am trying to split the year, month and day up into three individual entries, seperated by '/'. The original text entry looks like:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :placeholder => 'YYYY/MM/DD' %>
```

I would like to split this into three text_fields, and append them together, and put it into the date entry in the database.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You often use textfields for dates because you then only needs one field. When you are having three different fields should you consider using select instead. Rails have a the date helper method `date_select`, so it would be somethink like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :date %>
```

This creates one select for years, one for months and one for days.
You can read more on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Answer (score 0):

Add three virtual attributes to the model:

```
attr_accessor :form_month, :form_day, :form_year
```

Then put the following in the **controller**, not the model:

```
def create
  # ...
  form_date = [ params[:form][:form_month], \
                params[:form][:form_day]  , 
                params[:form][:form_year] ].join("/")

  @my_model.date = Date.parse(form_date)

  # ... save and return ...
end
```

It would be a good idea to manually check each form parameter for validity. `Date#parse` may spit out the incorrect date if fed an incomplete date string.

```
Date.parse "2005/11/4"
# => Fri, 04 Nov 2005

Date.parse "/11/4"
# => Mon, 04 Nov 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

```
<%= f.input :deadline, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 1, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

Do you have many options.